# Graph library API

Tags: python, api, graph, python-3.x

I am creating a library to support some standard graph traversals. Some of the graphs are defined explicitly: i.e., all edges are added by providing a data structure, or by repeatedly calling a relevant method. Some graphs are only defined implicitly: i.e., I only can provide a function that, given a node, will return its children (in particular, all the infinite graphs I traverse must be defined implicitly, of course).

The traversal generator needs to be highly customizable. For example, I should be able to specify whether I want DFS post-order/pre-order/in-order, BFS, etc.; in which order the children should be visited (if I provide a `key` that sorts them); whether the set of visited nodes should be maintained; whether the back-pointer (pointer to parent) should be yielded along with the node; etc.

I am struggling with the API design for this library (the implementation is not complicated at all, once the API is clear). I want it to be elegant, logical, and concise. Is there any graph library that meets these criteria that I can use as a template (doesn't have to be in Python)?

Of course, if there's a Python library that already does all of this, I'd like to know, so I can avoid coding my own.

(I'm using Python 3.)

Comment: Basically you have 2 higher level options, store connections as adjacency (possibly sparse) matrix or adjacency as list in the vertices. Which wan you want to choose is up to you. Both approaches have benefits, adn downsides.

Comment: @joojaa: For implicitly defined graphs (which may even be infinite), I would only store the set of visited nodes, the set of discovered nodes, and optionally a back-reference from each node to its parent. But in any case, this is an implementation detail; my question is exclusively about the API design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to handle infinite graphs then you are going to need some kind of functional interface to graphs (as you say in the q).  so i would make that the standard representation and provide helper functions that take other representations and generate a functional representation.

for the results, maybe you can yield (you imply a generator and i think that is a good idea) a series of result objects, each of which represents a node.  if the user wants more info, like backlinks, they call a method on that, and the extra information is provided (calculated lazily, where possible, so that you avoid that cost for people that don't need it).

you don't mention if the graph is directed or not.  obviously you can treat all graphs as directed and return both directions.  but then the implementation is not as efficient.  typically (eg [jgrapht](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/)) libraries have different interfaces for different kinds of graph.

(i suspect you're going to have to iterate a lot on this, before you get a good balance between elegant api and efficiency)

finally, are you aware of the [functional graph library](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/fgl/)?  i am not sure how it will help, but i remember thinking (years ago!) that the api there was a nice one.

Comment: Thank you. The functional interface is a necessity for an implicit graph; however, I got to like the idea behind the Boost Graph Library where there are different "levels" of the interface supported (depending on which operations can be performed quickly). This seems to cover the situations anywhere from the pure functional representation all the way to the full node-node matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The traversal algorithm and the graph data structure implementation should be separate, and should talk to each other only through the standard API. (If they are coupled, each traversal algorithm would have to be rewritten for every implementation.)

So my question really has two parts:

1. How to design the API for the graph data structure (used by graph algorithms such as traversals and by client code that creates/accesses graphs)
2. How to design the API for the graph traversal algorithms (used by client code that needs to traverse a graph)

I believe [C++ Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) answers both parts of my question very well. I would expect it can be (theoretically) rewritten in Python, although there may be some obstacles I don't see until I try.

Incidentally, I found a website that deals with question 1 in the context of Python: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGraphApi. Unfortunately, it hasn't been updated since Aug 2011.